# Linq To Nhibernate - Separated queries

Tags: linq, nhibernate

I've got the following situation:

```
        var totalRecords = (from entry in invalidAccEntryRepository
                            select entry).Where(entry =>
                               entry.CustomerAccountInfo.CustomerAccountName == CustomerAccountName &&
                               entry.CustomerAccountInfo.CustomerAccountId == CustomerAccountId).Count();
```

vs.

```
        var totalRecords = (from entry in invalidAccEntryRepository
                            select entry);

        if (CustomerAccountInfoFilterActive)
        {
            totalRecords.Where(entry =>
                               entry.CustomerAccountInfo.CustomerAccountName == CustomerAccountName &&
                               entry.CustomerAccountInfo.CustomerAccountId == CustomerAccountId);
        }

        totalRecordsCount = totalRecords.Count();
```

The first query works completely but the second query only executes the only

```
var totalRecords = (from entry in invalidAccEntryRepository
                            select entry);
```

and ignores the conditionally added where expression.

Anyone know what the problem could be? Do you need more info?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't actually applying the where. In your `if`, use this instead:

```
totalRecords = totalRecords.Where(entry =>
                               entry.CustomerAccountInfo.CustomerAccountName == CustomerAccountName &&
                               entry.CustomerAccountInfo.CustomerAccountId == CustomerAccountId);
```